# How to generate complex Makefiles, e.g. from a template

Tags: templates, makefile

Makefiles are really really useful. But, the syntax is somewhat complex and limited. For a project, I need to create targets 1 to n, and would really like to write something like this:

```
all : target1 ... target100

target%d : target%d.pre
    ./script.py %d
```

I would like to have `make` capture the variable (`%d`) and then use it throughout the rule. I could imagine that is is possible to do this with a complex use of patterns (%.xyz) and `patsubst`s, but this would be very clumsy and unreadable.

I'm thinking of using a template engine like [Cheetah](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/) to write a template (which can contain loops) that would then be converted into a Makefile. Does anyone have a better idea, or experience with this?

Comment: What's wrong with target%: target%.pre (carriage return, tab) ./script.py $*

Comment: ah, cool! From reading the docs I thought only suffixes (%.o) were possible, but not prefixes. Nice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As beta pointed out in a comment, the second part is actually solved by

```
target% : target%d.pre
    ./script.py %d
```

Given that, the first part can be solved by:

```
files := $(shell for i in `seq 1 100`; do echo target$$i; done)

all : $(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), which can do all the makefile generation for you.